# iframe YouTube demo will not work on iPad Safari browser

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I refer to the demo code for the YouTube iframe demo located at: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo.  This works perfectly on my desktop and my iPhone, but it will not do so on my iPad in the Safari browser.  I obtain a black screen instead.  I have modified the code to prevent it auto starting (I have a button now for that).  I also write event.target.getPlayerState() to a div on the screen so that I can see what is going on.  I wish to use to use the iFrame player and to control it using Javascript.

When it starts up I obtain the still frame from the video (as expected) and the red play button.  The getPlayerState() is 5 at this time (video cued).  As soon as I hit play the player iframe goes black and the getPlayerState() changes to 3 (buffering).  That is it, it will just sit there for hours without change.

I get the same black screen when I try the demo located at: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo.

I have no difficulty playing a video the YouTube website.  Also if I go to any video on the Youtube site and get the iframe embed link then I have no difficulty playing this from a web page.  This of course does not have a a Javascript interface.

Has anyone any suggestions?  What other info should I provide.

Many thanks.

Peter

This has since fixed itself.  But now the demo code will not work on Internet Explorer, the on ready is not firing.  There are many posts regarding this on Stackoverflow, but all marked closed.  I will investigate further and if necessary open a new post.

Comment: You might have embedded a flash player and your ipad doesn't support flash. That might be the reason.

Comment: Please share your code